# Explain this obscure ASP.NET bug

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I was just pushing a website to production, which worked fine in a QA environment. The patch involved DLL dependency updates, and some database scripts.

I will cut to the chase and explain the error that took me 4 hours to figure out. One of my database scripts created a stored procedure, which was missing [dbo] before its name. So instead of becoming [dbo].[myProcedure] it became [shawn].[myProcedure]. When the script was executed from code via the System.Data.SqlClient library, it killed the entire ASP.NET worker process. This caused the application to restart and redirect me back to the login screen. The procedure was only called conditionally, and quite infrequently, so it was difficult to reproduce.

Because it took out the entire ASP.NET worker process, it was extremely difficult to debug. I had no way of catching the error. Eventually I noticed this in the Windows Event Log:

```
Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException

Message: Unable to find assembly 'Shawn.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

(Note: Root namespace renamed to protect the innocent.)

And then, 2 seconds later:

```
EventType clr20r3, P1 w3wp.exe, P2 6.0.3790.3959, P3 45d6968e, P4 mscorlib, P5 2.0.0.0, P6 4889dc80, P7 4687, P8 4b, P9 shawn.data.dataaccess, P10 NIL.
```

At this point I figured it was a mismatched assembly version, [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache) conflict? or something similar. I checked every reference throughout my project, and tried tons of different things. I eventually looked for all references to the namespace Shawn.Data.DataAccess and logged to a file every few lines to find where the application was failing. This led me to the correct stored procedure.

[TLDR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TLDR): Why would the lack of [dbo] on a single script cause the entire ASP.NET worker process to crash?

Comment: Are you dealing with CLR based stored procedures? OR a user defined type returned from the stored procedure?

Comment: everything is based of the sqlclient class using commands and datasets.

Comment: Personally I think the first exception log is because requests were happening whilst you were patching the dll, causing it to be temporarily be unavailable.. I think the 2 seconds later error is once your patched code has loaded, and run some data access code on a background thread, which was buggy- causing an exception which bubbled to the top of the worker process, and caused it to exit.

Answer (score 3):

It crashed because your data access functionality could not find the stored procedure, and when you called it, well, since the stored procedure couldn't be found, the run time generated an unhandled exception.

As for it killing the entire ASP.NET worker process, that's because you had an unhandled exception. The process could not recover from the exception because it was not handled (no try/catch around your read, etc.), therefore the only thing it could do is restart the process.

As for the why the [dbo] versus [shawn] causes a crash... well, that has to do with ownership of objects in SQL Server.  Users are able to access any object owned by DBO without specifying an owner, but if the object is owned by an account that is NOT DBO, then you must provide a fully qualified name. (i.e. [shawn].myStoredProcedure).   Read more here: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/understanding-the-difference-between-owners-and-schemas-in-sql-server.

Comment: ive never heard of an unhandled exception crashing the entire worker process

Comment: @Shawn, @Beska Read this and it will make sense, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx

Comment: A simple unhandled exception from a missing stored procedure does not explain the SerializationException that is being logged.

Comment: Slight correction: typically, the default schema for a login is DBO. If a login calls an object not in their default schema, it must be fully qualified.

Comment: You are right that traditionally an uncaught exception won't crash a worker process, but thats for threads that are executing in a http context (basically, the https "exec" function catches the exeption).. but if you have an uncaught exception in another thread, such as a timer event- the worker process will terminate.

Answer (score 0):

You must be doing something really unusual to bring down the worker process.  It doesn't have anything to do with the database error - it's got to be related to where that error happens in your code, likely on a background thread, but even then ASP.NET generally protects itself from being brought down by uncaught exceptions.

It's best practice to always surround all code in any methods that are executed on threads with a try-catch.

Comment: It really isn't that unusual, and asp.net only catches request handling execution, as it assumes that a request execution exception shouldn't bring the entire app down.. any other execution outside of a http request is handled just like any other .net app, and will bubble to the top and thusly cause the process to exit.

I think this behavior was set in .NET 2.